# Stopping a ServerSocket accept() loop thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I'm implementing a very basic API to have a better control over ServerSocket and Sockets, but I'm in a very weird problem that I cannot fix due to my lack of threads knowledge. Let me explain it.

In my class SocketStreamReceiver I use a secondary thread to listen for new sockets with `ServerSocket#accept()`. There are 2 methods: start() and stop() that the client can use to start (creating a thread and begin listening with `accept()`) and stop (closing the ServerSocket and destroying the thread) my SocketStreamReceiver.

**How will you implement stop() method?** Keep in mind that stop() can be called inside doSomething(), in the same secondary thread started by start(). You can change anything you want: you can create the ServerSocket inside the thread if you want, just before while(running).

```
public class SocketStreamReceiver{
    ...
    private Thread thread;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private boolean running;
    ...

    public void start () throws IOException{
        if (thread != null) return;

        server = new ServerSocket (port);
        thread = new Thread (new Runnable (){
            @Override
            public void run (){
                try{
                    while (running){
                        Socket socket = server.accept ();
                        doSomething (socket);
                    }
                }catch (SocketException e){
                    ...
                }catch (IOException e){
                    ...
                }
            }
        }, "SocketStreamReceiver");
        thread.start ();
    }

    public void stop () throws IOException{
        if (thread == null) return;

        //code...

        thread = null;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT - Solution:**

```
public class SocketStreamReceiver{
    private Thread thread;
    private ServerSocket server;
    private volatile boolean running;
    ...

    public synchronized void start () throws IOException{
        if (thread != null) throw new IllegalStateException ("The receiver is already started.");

        server = new ServerSocket (port);
        thread = new Thread (new Runnable (){
            @Override
            public void run (){
                try{
                    running = true;
                    while (running){
                        doSomething (server.accept ());
                        ...
                    }
                }catch (SocketException e){
                    ...
                }catch (IOException e){
                    ...
                }
            }
        }, "SocketStreamReceiver");
        thread.start ();
    }

    public synchronized void stop (){
        if (thread == null) return;

        running = false;
        try{
            if (server != null){
                server.close ();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){}

        thread = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just do

```
public void stop() {
    running = false;
    try{
        if (server != null) server.close ();
    } catch (IOException ignored){
    }
}
```

It doesn't appear you even need the running flag. However I would use it in your server accept code to determine if an Exception is expected or not. i.e. when running == false ignore all exceptions.

I would make `running` volatile.

I would make start()/stop() synchronized if you can run these from different threads.

Comment: If server.close() is called and after we do server.accept() what will happen? Does ServerSocket block the thread?

Comment: The accept() will throw a SocketException, which you have to catch anyway.

Comment: Why do you catch the exception AND throws it?

Comment: @MByD, because I forgot to remove it. Thank you.